# Jenkins: send multiple params in URL trigger

Tags: jenkins

I have a Jenkins job which checks a file version...

This project is parameterized:

```
Multi-line String Parameter = server
```

Powershell command

```
$servers = ($env:servers).Split([Environment]::NewLine, [StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries)
foreach ($server in $servers) {ls "\\$server\c$\update.dll" | % versioninfo}
```

I trigger it using the URL:

http://MY_JENKINS_SERVER/job/FILE_VERSION/buildWithParameters?servers=10.10.10.1

it works and I get:

```
 ProductVersion   FileVersion      FileName                            
 --------------   -----------      -------- 
 11.1.1.16        11.1.1.16        \\10.10.10.1\c$\update.dll
```

But I want to send multiple IP's in the trigger URL, eg

10.10.10.1

10.10.10.2

10.10.10.7

So I output something like:

```
 ProductVersion   FileVersion      FileName                            
 --------------   -----------      -------- 
 11.1.1.16        11.1.1.16        \\10.10.10.1\c$\update.dll
 11.1.1.15        11.1.1.15        \\10.10.10.2\c$\update.dll
 11.1.1.15        11.1.1.15        \\10.10.10.7\c$\update.dll
```

Anyone know how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using "Multiline String Parameter", you will have to provide all the required values separated by newline character. Generally, \n is considered for newline, however, you will have to "url-escape" it. Use this %0A as newline character.

So, your POST URL should be something like this :

```
curl -v -X POST <jenkins_url>/<job_name>/buildWithParameters?server=11.1.1.16%0A11.1.1.15%0A11.1.1.15
```

More reference on url-escape characters : https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp

Comment: Thankyou, i will try this.

Comment: I have been really busy, I will try this and report back as soon as I can, thanks.